# OOP - Loan class error

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, inheritance

Can u help me to solve this problem.. im so lost..

```
package Object;

public class Loan {

  private double annualinterestRate;
  private int numberofyears;
  private double loanamount;

  public Loan(){
  }

  public Loan(double annualinterestRate, int numberofyears, double loanamount)
  {
      this.annualinterestRate = annualinterestRate;
      this.numberofyears = numberofyears;
      this.loanamount = loanamount;
  }

  public double getAnnualinterestRate() {
      return annualinterestRate;
  }

  public void setAnnualinterestRate(double annualinterestRate) {
      this.annualinterestRate = annualinterestRate;
  }

  public int getNumberofyears() {
      return numberofyears;
  }

  public void setNumberofyears(int numberofyears) {
      this.numberofyears = numberofyears;
  }

  public double getLoanamount() {
      return loanamount;
  }

  public void setLoanamount(double loanamount) {
      this.loanamount = loanamount;
  }



  public double getMonthlyPayment()
  {
      double MonthIntRate = annualinterestRate/1200;
      double MonthlyPayment = (loanamount*MonthIntRate)/(1-(1/Math.pow(1+MonthIntRate,numberofyears*12)));
      return MonthlyPayment;
  }

  public double getTotalPayment()
  {
      return getMonthlyPayment()*numberofyears*12;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
      return "Annualint=" +annualinterestRate+ "Y=" +numberofyears+ "Amnt=" +loanamount+ "Monthly =" + MonthlyPayment();
  }

}
```

There have some error in last method of String to String in Monthly Payment. It says :
***Multiple markers at this line
    - The method MonthlyPayment() is undefined for the 
     type Loan
    - MonthlyPayment cannot be resolved to a variable

What is the mistake here

Comment: The method name is `getMonthlyPayment()` not `MonthlyPayment()`, Use the correct name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct the compilation error as below

**Error Code**

```
public String toString()
      {
          return "Annualint=" +annualinterestRate+ "Y=" +numberofyears+ "Amnt=" +loanamount+ "Monthly =" + MonthlyPayment();
      }
```

As mentioned above, `MonthlyPayment()` is not a declared method, rather `getMonthlyPayment()` has to be used.

**Correct Code**

```
public String toString()
      {
          return "Annualint=" +annualinterestRate+ "Y=" +numberofyears+ "Amnt=" +loanamount+ "Monthly =" + getMonthlyPayment();
      }
```

Comment: Thanks you <3 it really help :)